# Javascript OnFocus and OnBlue events

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, onblur, onfocus

I want to create `onfocus` and `onBlur` events in Javascript. I have a found a solution which is in jQuery but not sure how to convert it into Javascript.

```
<textarea id='postitTextArea'  ></textarea>
$('input,textarea').focus(function()
{
  $(this).data('placeholder', $(this).attr('placeholder'))
        .attr('placeholder', '');
}).blur(function()
{
  $(this).attr('placeholder', $(this).data('placeholder'));
});
```

The above code is working fine. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not use jquery ?

Comment: i want to know how to do it in javascript. All the methods i have is in Javascript.

Comment: http://ejohn.org/files/142/ check out why jquery is faster in performance in the link

Comment: i am using classes in Javascript and all the methods are pure javascript so i dont want to create Jquery i want to follow the standard and all methods should be in Javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
var obj = document.getElementById('postitTextArea');

obj.removeAttribute('onfocus');
obj.removeAttribute('onblur');

obj.addEventListener('focus', function() {
  // your js code for focus event
});
obj.addEventListener('blur', function() {
   // your js code for blur event
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var inputs, index;

inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (index = 0; index < inputs.length; ++index) {
    inputs[index].onfocus = function(){
     // Your script
    };
    inputs[index].onblur = function(){
     // Your script
    };
}

//similarly for textarea
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the JavaScript code for the jQuery code you have provided,

HTML:

```
<textarea id='postitTextArea' placeholder="placeholder text" onfocus="focusAction()" onblur="blurAction()"></textarea>
```

JS:

```
function focusAction(){
    var target = document.getElementById('postitTextArea');
    var setAttrVal = target.setAttribute('placeholder',' ');
    console.log('placeholder: ' + setAttrVal);
}
function blurAction(){
    var target = document.getElementById('postitTextArea');
    var setAttrVal = target.setAttribute('placeholder','placeholder text');
    console.log('placeholder: ' + setAttrVal);
}
```